# Alternative to webservice for pulling data form mysql?

Tags: php, .net, mysql, web-services

I'm using a .net desktop application to call a php webservice and get me some data from mySQL, the problem is calling the service is not possible so is there any alternative way to get that data? All suggestions and ideas are welcome.

Comment: Do you have access to the mySQL server?

Comment: Why is it not possible? What is possible then?

Comment: direct sql call with the help mysql drivers?

Comment: or may be you can pull a simple URL, this would be the simplest one, but you will have to take care of authentication stuff

Comment: @Arfeen : I thought of doing that but can you tell me how that is different from calling a webservice both will require an http call

Comment: @LewisBenge: yes but i cant grant access to my desktop application and give it to users that would be a security risk.

Comment: @user1064950 ok so i thought u can't use web services like SOAP etc, i thought u could call a simple HTTP call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the above comments, you only have two options which neither appear to be valid in your circumstance:

1) You create a data access layer that connects directly to the database using a TCP/IP connection
2) You proxy the database through a webservice, albeit SOAP/REST or even something like WCF Data Services using OData.

If you require real time access to the database, you have no other alternatives.